# Are Vinyl floorings designed for High traffic best on Basement concrete?

Tags: concrete, basement, flooring, subfloor, vinyl-flooring

Have to install Vinyl flooring on my concrete basement. my basement flooring is not 100% flat.
I see a lots of 1/8" low spots and some places have 1/4" low spot within 10 feet. I have to grind down some high spot in some places.

I believe I am not only one in this world who is running with the situation/problem. lol. May be some of them found solutions or some are not thinking about too much.

But still I almost planned to buy 12 mm wear layer of flooring because this is rated for residential purpose. But I later found this doesn't have as much strong edge ( clicking mechanism)  as 22 mm wear layer has.

so I am concern about breaking/loosing the edge over period of times. I am not too much concern about scratches. I am more concern how long the floor will hold.

I think 22 MM layer of plank is more scratch resistant, but that's not enough. its also better in high traffic area.

Do you think 22 or more mm wear of flooring (designed for High traffic ) will be better on concrete type of sub flooring ?
I see, each 22 mm wear layer of plank is 1 pound heavier than 12 mm one's

Note*- I don't have plan to put OSB/plywood as underlayment because their unavailability of higher price.

Please advice.

Comment: Most plank flooring requires a flat surface.  Your floor is above any limits of flatness.  There are leveling compounds that you might be able to use to make the floor flat.

Comment: You ask about "wear layers" of 12 & 22mm thickness. 12mm is ~1/2" and 22mm is nearly 1". Is that the total thickness of the flooring you're looking to install or is that actually the "wear layer" before you get to the substrate? Also, I'm not clear what your actual question is. The title asks one thing, but in the body of the question there's a totally different question asking what we think (which sounds like you're asking for opinions which makes it off topic). Please [edit] your post to clarify these details.